# iOS browser loses window scroll event when you go back to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, prototypejs, mobile-safari

With the Prototype Javascript framework, you would write the following code to listen for the window scroll event.

```
document.observe(
   'dom:loaded',
    function() {
        Event.observe(
            window,
            'scroll',
            function(event) {
                console.info(event);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

On iOS's Safari browser, the scroll handler is no longer fired when you leave the page and hit back. Android's browser does not have this problem. Someone filed a [solution for jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3036), but I use Prototype. How do you make sure you are always listening for the scroll event with Prototype?

Comment: From what I read of the linked fix it only applies to jQuery Mobile which doesn't leave the page at all but updates the page by AJAX. Since you are not using that and are actually leaving the page I assume there is a different cause.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the details are in Prototype, but as far as mobile browser support for the traditional scroll event it does not exist. You will get a scroll event fired when the scrolling is determined to be over, which I have found to be awkward. If you dig into the jQueryMobile source code you will see how they dealt with it. For example the fixed position toolbars. They hide them anytime a touchstart event is fired. They do this because they have no concrete way to determine if the app is being scrolled or not. And since there is no event being fired as the view is being scrolled they do not know how to reposition the fixed toolbars. Once the scroll end event has fired or the touchend/touchstop/touchcancel event fires they redisplay the toolbar at the correct position.

Comment: I am aware that scroll events on iOS and Android do not fire until the user stops scrolling. I don't care about this issue. I only care when it stops firing scroll events completely when you go back to the page in iOS.